# parse extra information in a link with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook

i have this link output from a facebook feed:

```
http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Ftravel%2F2014%2Fapr%2F25%2Fitaly-puglia-salento-region&h=2AQF4oNrg&s=1
```

and i need the final ouput like this:

```
http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2014/apr/25/italy-puglia-salento-region
```

so basically i have this bit to remove:

```
 http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=
```

i was trying a regex in javascript but not very familiar with it:

```
Body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
regex = ???
Matches = regex.exec(Body);
```

any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
function extractLinkFromFb(fbLink) {
    var encodedUri = fbLink.split('?u=');
    return decodeURIComponent(encodedUri[1]);
}

var link = 'http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Ftravel%2F2014%2Fapr%2F25%2Fitaly-puglia-salento-region&h=2AQF4oNrg&s=1';


var myExtractedLink = extractLinkFromFb(link);
```

The function extractLinkFromFb() will return your link.

Answer (score 0):

Before decoding the url, you can use this regex to grab the piece you want:

```
var myregex = /u=([^&#\s]+)/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    thematch = matchArray[1];
} else {
    thematch = "";
}
```

- The parentheses in the regex captures the match to Group 1
- `u=` serves as a delimiter, but is not captured in Group 1
- `[^&#\s]` matches one character that is not a `&`, `#` or whitespace character. Tweak to suit.
- the `+` quantifier matches one or more of these characters

Comment: how would you wrap that in a a whole script?

Comment: @manny999 Sorry, I was just interested in answering a regex question, not in delivering a whole script. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Ftravel%2F2014%2Fapr%2F25%2Fitaly-puglia-salento-region&h=2AQF4oNrg&s=1';
            var str1 = "http://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=";
            var str2 = "&h=2AQF4oNrg&s=1";


            var url = url.replace(str1, ""); 
            var url=url.split("&h=")
            var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(url[0]); // =http://www.theguardian.com/travel/2014/apr/25/italy-puglia-salento-region
            //alert (uri_dec);
            //console.log (uri_dec);
```